# i'm trying to push my python-django app to heroku, here is the code from the teminal and settings.py :

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I get the error in the terminal ( AttributeError: module 'posixpath' has no attribute 'adspath')
i tried changing the BASE_DIR file and nothing worked, I fixed the static files and it didn't work either, be patient with my problem please, I have been trying for 3 days to upload this app and this is my final resort. thank you for checking out my question..

This is my terminal after running git push heroku master:

```
git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 6962, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6962/6962), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4022/4022), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6962/6962), 15.05 MiB | 189.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6962 (delta 1888), reused 6927 (delta 1865), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.9.0
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting asgiref==3.2.10
remote:          Downloading asgiref-3.2.10-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url==0.5.0
remote:          Downloading dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting dj-static==0.0.6
remote:          Downloading dj-static-0.0.6.tar.gz (3.4 kB)
remote:        Collecting Django==3.1.2
remote:          Downloading Django-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
remote:        Collecting django-bootstrap3==14.1.0
remote:          Downloading django_bootstrap3-14.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==20.0.4
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
remote:        Collecting pytz==2020.1
remote:          Downloading pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
remote:        Collecting sqlparse==0.4.1
remote:          Downloading sqlparse-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
remote:        Collecting static3==0.7.0
remote:          Downloading static3-0.7.0.tar.gz (24 kB)
remote:        Collecting whitenoise==5.2.0
remote:          Downloading whitenoise-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
remote:        Building wheels for collected packages: dj-static, static3
remote:          Building wheel for dj-static (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for dj-static (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for dj-static: filename=dj_static-0.0.6-py3-none-any.whl size=3051 
sha256=c8389fabbd7eda5b003f60986d0674c04ce2e162126ae3b87eb5059831f0d184
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache- 
j02lo4pu/wheels/b5/10/4a/83f0c20117a4580af66c382f5cd1c689e6a8818a042ffdedd3
remote:          Building wheel for static3 (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for static3 (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for static3: filename=static3-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl size=18606 
sha256=5731bb65876d7b56b86eb47e33f4879111185ae7ab86e9d8d16cb5ecd036ba33
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache- 
j02lo4pu/wheels/67/88/26/362b5f8314043c6241ed324b9f76ddf48328b775923b39590a
remote:        Successfully built dj-static static3
remote:        Installing collected packages: asgiref, dj-database-url, static3, dj-static, pytz, 
sqlparse, Django, django-bootstrap3, gunicorn, whitenoise
remote:        Successfully installed Django-3.1.2 asgiref-3.2.10 dj-database-url-0.5.0 dj-static- 
0.0.6 django-bootstrap3-14.1.0 gunicorn-20.0.4 pytz-2020.1 sqlparse-0.4.1 static3-0.7.0 whitenoise- 
5.2.0
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/tmp/build_1d5fef1c/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "/tmp/build_1d5fef1c/manage.py", line 18, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
remote:            settings.INSTALLED_APPS
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 
83, in __getattr__
remote:            self._setup(name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 
70, in _setup
remote:            self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 
177, in __init__
remote:            mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in 
import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:          File "/tmp/build_1d5fef1c/learning_log/settings.py", line 160, in <module>
remote:            BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.adspath(__file__))
remote:        AttributeError: module 'posixpath' has no attribute 'adspath'
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to mynewapplog.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/mynewapplog.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mynewapplog.git'
```

And this is Setting.py:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '(*ru69!qi-6ei^kfnrw@^t_9_mnbttt$((bgx6%!10hz$iy$7z'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'intense-depths-58584.herokuapp.com',
    '127.0.0.1',
    'localhost',
    'admin',
    'topic',
]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

# Third party apps.
     'bootstrap3',

# My apps
    'learning_logs',
    'users',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'learning_log.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'learning_log.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
   },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# My setting (((((((this takes the place of the changes in views.py in the users file)))))))
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# My settings.
LOGIN_URL = '/users/login/'

# Settings for django-bootstrap3
BOOTSTRAP3 = {
    'include_jquery': True,
}

# Heruko settings.
cwd = os.getcwd()
if cwd == '/app' or cwd[:4] == '/tmp':
    import dj_database_url

    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')
    }

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Porto' header for request.is_secure().
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host readers.
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Static asset configuration.
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.adspath(__file__))
    STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

Comment: Run `python3 --version` and add that exact version to a `runtime.txt` file like `python-3.7.3` and try again

Comment: I already have the 3.9.0 version in my runtime.txt file

Comment: But do you use python3.9 on your machine?

Comment: yes, that is what I'm working on + it's the only python version i have installed on my machine to avoid any trouble with multiple versions.

Answer (score 0):

The first version of Django to support Python 3.9 will be [Django 3.1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1.3/), which is scheduled to be released November 2, 2020.

Comment: The easiest approach would be to install Python 3.8.6 until the next Django release. It's also possible that some of your other dependencies don't support 3.9 yet.

Comment: yeah thank you for the info, I knew upgrading so fast to 3.9.0 is a bad idea :/